# Average a CSV Column

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to average out column 4 in my csv file, by having the function read the file and then spit out an average. The way the program works right now is that every time it is run your answers are appended to the csv file. So to use this code right now you would have to run it a few times or just make the csv file and pre-fill it with data. The last lines of codes with a '#' is where I am working on right now.

```
import csv
import datetime
# imports modules

now = datetime.datetime.now()
# define current time when file is executed

how = str(raw_input("How are you doing?"))
why = str(raw_input("Why do you feel that way?"))
scale_of_ten = int(raw_input("On a scale of 1-10. With 10 being happy and 1 being sad. How happy are you?"))
#creates variables for csv file

x = [now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),how,why,scale_of_ten]
# creates list for variables to be written in

with open ('happy.csv','ab') as f:
    wtr = csv.writer(f)
    wtr.writerow(x)
    f.close()

col = 4

values = []

stats = open('happy.csv')

with open('happy.csv','r') as f: #
    for line in csv.readlines():# 
        elements = line.strip().split(',') #
        values.append(int(elements[col]))#

csum = sum(values) #
cavg = sum(values)/len(values) #
print ("Sum of column %d: %f" % (col,csum)) #
print ("avg of column %d: %f" % (col, cavg)) #
```

However, I get this error from following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286560/python-using-excel-csv-file-to-read-only-certain-columns-and-rows) from the first answer at the top:

```
  File "stacked.py", line 28, in <module>
    for line in csv.readline():#
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Thanks for your help in advance. I'm tempted to jump into panda.

Comment: you need `for lines in f.readlines():`

Comment: Aside: in Python 3 (which I'm assuming you're using from the `print` syntax) you open `csv` files for reading using `open('happy.csv', 'r', newline='')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

`csv`is a module which does not have attribute `readline`.
What you need to do is to readlines from the csv file, not from the `csv` module

On line 28 you need `for lines in f.readlines():`(as f is the name you gave it on line 27).

Comment: That works. Now I'm working on a list index out of range on line 29. Thanks for the help. I should be able to figure this one out.

Comment: @RobertBirch: Remember that if you have 4 cols, the last one has index 3

Comment: Right, just like lists i.e. l[0],l[1],l[2],l[3].

Comment: `for lines in f:` would work too; there's no need to read the whole file into memory at once.

Comment: You right, and that's really a non-trivial detail since a csv file might have thousands of lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want use CSV module. It doesn't have `readline` function. Yun can use [reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
spamreader = csv.reader('happy.csv', delimiter=',', quotechar='')
for line in spamreader:
    ...
```

Or

```
with open('happy.csv','r') as f:
    for line in f.read():
        ...
```